# Command line flag to disable all types of caches in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I would like to disable memory cache, disk cache and other types of caches in Chrome with a command line flag. Right now I start Chrome with

`open /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app --args --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --disk-cache-size=1 --media-cache-size=1`

But still I am getting resources from the memory cache in Chrome. Is there a way to completely disable all caches from Chrome via a command line flag?

I do not want to do the following :-

- press the disable Cache button in the dev tools. I do not want to press this cos of another Chrome bug which occurs when this button is checked.
- Press and hold the refresh button for hard reload. Doing this bypasses service workers too, which I do not want since I am testing that.
- Command + Shift + R - Same reason as point above

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was using windows, and `/dev/null` doesn't in windows, so I just tried `--disk-cache-dir=/dev/null` which as i said doesn't exist, and it worked.
So what I'm saying is try typing in some random path like `/bla/bla` as the path and chrome would stop caching because that path doesn't exist